# How to unpack nested map with "recursive" $objectToArray or other methods in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to replace / **$set** a nested KV map into separate key and value collections for further use during the query process and this needs to happen recursively for however the nested the map may be. In the example below its only two layers, but they could be going deeper. The relevant function I found for this is **$objectToArray** which works great for the first layer, but afterward I am unsure how to unpack the nested map that is inside the outer map **.v** object. The keys and values are **NOT known in advance**, so I can't hardcode an unpack of e.g. **$nestedMap.1001**. I do however know how nested it is ahead of time - because my query defines that it e.g. only inspects the first 2, 3 or N "layers". So I do not need infinite recursion.

```
{
  "nestedMap": {
    "1001": {
      "0": "A",
      "1": "B",
      "2": "C",
      "3": "D"
    },
    "1002": {
      "0": "A",
      "1": "B",
      "2": "C",
      "3": "D"
    }
  }
}
```

The goal would be for it to look like this probably:

```
{
  "nestedMap": [
    {
      "k": "1001",
      "v": [
        {
          "k": "0",
          "v": "A"
        },
        {
          "k": "1",
          "v": "B"
        },
        {
          "k": "2",
          "v": "C"
        },
        {
          "k": "3",
          "v": "D"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "k": "1002",
      "v": [
        {
          "k": "0",
          "v": "A"
        },
        {
          "k": "1",
          "v": "B"
        },
        {
          "k": "2",
          "v": "C"
        },
        {
          "k": "3",
          "v": "D"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have prepared this [MongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QRDTt7BlWde) with my current attempt that I do not know how to get further with. I have searched for all keywords I could think of but found no answers here or on other sources that can "recursively" unpack a map. I would prefer a solution that operates within a single aggregation stage because I have a lot more logic that needs to be combined to also deal with nested unnamed arrays. So it would not really work out too well if each KV unpack is its separate stage that is hard coded to always go one layer further down. If that is the only option though please let me know how to do that and I'll see if I can adapt the rest of my code to work with that too.

Thank you very much for any pointers toward a solution.

Comment: had an [answer](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RiqecHhaorL) but missed the recursive part

Comment: i think [$function](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eXDy1-jjL41) would be easiest if u wwant n levels deep

Comment: Thank you for your input. A javascript $function might work but those are by far the worst performers as far as I read advice on them, so I would like to avoid it.

Comment: you are correct on performance.  im not aware of anything that handles reursion other than graphLookup

Comment: I do know the most inner path I care about. So I would know that it needs to be unpacked e.g. 4 times, so it's not unknown infinite recursion. But my problem is that because I don't know the names ahead of time I cant chain 4 unpacks as 4 aggregation stages manually. I was hoping that from one unpack I could then access .v and do it again (and again and again if neeed).

Comment: Did you try `$function`? It may work better than you would expect.

Comment: I have not used it yet, I am open to using it if there seems to be no better alternative. How would I accomplish this using a function?

Comment: See solution linked by @cmgchess

Comment: oooooh that was a playground link. missed it haha. thank you

Comment: @Arkensor btw i didnt fully test the js code. you are free to write answer with what worked for you

Answer (score 0):

This can't be accomplished recursively unless you use a function that can recurse, but it **can** be accomplished by modifying the aggregation expression depending on how deep to go. Since you mentioned that you know beforehand how many layers you need to process, your code can generate the required expression.

For 2 layers deep:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      nestedMap: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $objectToArray: "$nestedMap"
          },
          in: {
            k: "$$this.k",
            v: {
              $objectToArray: "$$this.v"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

For 3 layers deep:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      nestedMap: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $objectToArray: "$nestedMap"
          },
          in: {
            k: "$$this.k",
            v: {
              $map: {
                input: {
                  $objectToArray: "$$this.v"
                },
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.k",
                  v: {
                    $objectToArray: "$$this.v"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This operates in a single aggregation stage for any number of layers.
Just replace the last `$objectToArray:"$$this.v"` with the `$map:{...}` block for each additional layer.

I realise this answer comes a little late, but I hope it's useful as I needed to find a similar solution.